# how can i make drop down menu for this items without them glitching or getting in the way of something

Tags: html, css

Hi all my question is how can i add the assignment pages ass drop down menu for the Actual assignment button.In my css code.I want them to appear downwards the assignment button and not to glitch and change the order of the other buttons i would appriciate the help.

```
    <body id="page3">                                         
<header>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="logo"> 
            <img src="../logo.png">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class=""><a href="smth.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="cont.html">Contact me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Assignments</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Assignment Week1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Assignment Week1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Assignment Week1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Assignment Week1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Assignment Week1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Assignments</h1>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
ul{
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top:10px;
}
ul li{
    display:inline-flex;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    padding:20px 25px;
    border:1px solid transparent;  
    transition:0.8s ease;
}
ul li a:hover{
background-color: white;
color:black;
}
ul li.active a{
    background-color: white;
color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear with reference to "glitch", but I think I understand your problem. There are a few things missing in the CSS to construct the basic dropdown.

1. The first level li should have 'position: relative' set
2. The second level ul should have a 'position: absolute' set
3. You will need to hide the nested ul by default, and then reveal on hover.

I'm sure there are many references to how to construct a proper CSS menu dropdown, below is some basic modifications that show the fundamental concept.

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top:10px;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li{
  display:inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}

ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 3.7rem;
  left: 0;
}

ul li ul li a {
  min-width: 200px;
}

ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  padding:20px 25px;
  border:1px solid transparent;  
  transition:0.8s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul li a:hover{
  background-color: white;
  color:black;
}

ul li.active a{
  background-color: white;
  color:black;
}

.title {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<body id="page3">                                         
  <header>
      <div class="main">
          <div class="logo"> 
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x80">
          </div>
          <ul>
              <li class=""><a href="smth.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="cont.html">Contact me</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Assignments</a>
                  <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Assignment Week1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Assignment Week1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Assignment Week1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Assignment Week1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Assignment Week1</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="title">
          <h1>Assignments</h1>
      </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```